# Can Snowpark be used to extract data from any database

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I was exploring snowpark, but wanted to know , if it provides flexibility to extract data from any database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Snowpark only operates in the secure sandbox environment in Snowflake.